# mod_rewrite and xmlhttprequest

Tags: mod-rewrite, xmlhttprequest

I guess mod_rewrite can do the trick, but I don't know how.  I have two scripts one listening port 8888 and another listening port 80. XMLHttpRequest can only listen one port, so how I configure mod_rewrite for this case?

Comment: you can't. not unless you do a full internal proxying of the request. redirecting the client to a different port runs into same-origin security restrictions

Comment: So I need mod_proxy or something like that? How I can configure that